# Trouble with file paths in JSP

Tags: html, jsp, path, anchor

I am having trouble with loading different documents using various tags in JSP.
I am using an anchor tag to download a file from the server for the user like so:

```
<a href="home/sample.txt" download>sample.txt</a>
```

My  project directory structure is:
[image]

The jsp that contains the link code is in yellow.

Whenever I click on the link to download the sample.txt file, it downloads a copy of FileBrowser.jsp instead

Furthermore, when I try to link and external css with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/styles.css"/>
```

The css is not getting loaded. Am I missing something with how paths work in a JSP project?

Comment: try `href="../assets` because with your JSP being in WEB-INF, its a folder back and then assests.

Comment: The picture might not show it well, but the JSP is in the WebContent folder, not the WEB_INF folder.

Comment: I fixed the issue, although I don't know why it was a problem. I had the @WebServlet annotation in the Browser.java (main servlet) equal to @WebServlet({"/", "/Browser"}). I took out the first slash and made it @WebServlet({"", "/Browser"}). Now all of my assets are working